# Concentration of sample covariance for dependent data

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, measure-concentration

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_T$ are sub-Gaussian random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ coming from a common distribution with population covariance $\Sigma$. If they are independent, it is known that the sample covariance converges to $\Sigma$ with high-probability. In fact, one can establish strong concentration bounds. My question is, can we say similar concentration results when $X_1, \ldots, X_T$ are dependent. I believe we need some sort of $\alpha$- mixing or $\beta$-mixing condition on the dependence structure. I found some related results for random variables (not random vectors) under some mixing conditions ([Rio 1993](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_1993__29_4_587_0.pdf)). But not sure whether this holds for random vectors or not? Any help will be appreciated.